# Compare two text files if contains match in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, compare, contains

I have been searching for an solution and haven't been able to find one for this situation.
How can I compare two text files so that it only displays match?
ipaddress.txt contains:

```
10.30.16.221
10.30.16.228
10.30.16.223
```

I have another text file that displays the dns name along with ip address.
dns.txt contains:

```
dogs.com 10.30.16.221
cats.com 10.30.16.222
snakes.com 10.30.16.223
```

How can I compare ipaddress.txt and dns.txt so that it only return lines that contains a matching ip address?
It should return

```
dogs.com 10.30.16.221
snakes.com 10.30.16.223
```

Answer (score 0):

Read all the lines of ipaddress.txt to a hashset:

```
var ips = File.ReadAllLines("ipaddress.txt").ToHashSet();
```

Then, for every line in DNS, ask the hashset whether it contaisn the IP from that line:

```
var matches = File.ReadAllLines("dns.txt").Where(line => hs.Contains(line.Split().Last()));
```

It's more efficient to do an exact query after extracting just the IP, than it is to e.g. put the IPs in a list and for each line of DNS ask "does this DNS line end with any of the IPs in the list". You could also look at something like `line[line.LastIndexOf(' ')+1..]` to extract the IP. Note that both of these assume that dns is nicely formed with no trailing spaces etc; if the data in it is a bit wonky you'll need to clean it up. You could also use something like:

```
var ips = File.ReadAllLines("ipaddress.txt");
var matches = File.ReadAllLines("dns.txt").Where(line => ips.Any(ip => line.Contains(ip)));
```

but it's potentially a lot more inefficient for large lists